# Convert image to a digital matrix using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have an image "felix.png" (280x280).

and I'm converting this image to digital matrix:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import array




img = Image.open('felix.png')
arr = array(img)
```

the shape of this array is (280,280,3) and I wonder why each pixel is represented with 3 dimensional array?

for example `arr[0][0]` is `[255,255,255]`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is a color image. The third dimension is color.
thus

```
r = arr[:,:,0]
g = arr[:,:,1]
b = arr[:,:,2]
```

if PIL opens the image as RGB.

This means a red pixel at point (x,y) would be [255, 0, 0], and a white pixel [255, 255, 255].